# MapReduce program not sharing string variables between main and mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a mapreduce program in which the String created in Main method has to be shared in Mapper class. This is using New mapreduce api. I coded properly and set the variable using configuration in main method as below.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmsss");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
String ImagesDir    = "/user/srini/images/"+ date;
conf.set("ImagesDir", ImagesDir);
```

and then I am picking the variable in Mapper class setup method as below. First created a variable in class as String OutputPath and then did the following in the setup.

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
OutputPath  = conf.get("ImagesDir");
```

and used this variable in map method. The problem is, the value in variable OutputPath is null all the time. I have tried this using JobConf in Old mapred API long back and it worked fine. Some how, its going wrong here. What could have been wrong. Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Job` constructors are deprecated, use the `Job.getInstance` method to create a Job object.

According to the documentation of the `getInstance` method, it actually copies the passed `Configuration` object, thus any modifications you make to the Configuration after you create the Job will not be visible to any part of the system. Simply move the configuration setup in front of the job creation, like so:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("ImagesDir", ImagesDir);
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do the configuration the way you do? If not, try this:

```
String ImagesDir = "/user/srini/images/"+ date;
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(ImageDir));
```

Just to remind, general rule is to name a variable is either `image_dir` or `imageDir`.

Comment: I do not want it as OutputFormat.. map method has to use this directory name. Not only this, i need to pass three more String variables to map method, which will be derived in main. This has been achieved without any problems in old mapred api, using JobConf and configure.. But not able to do the same with new api using setup and Configuration...